# Create curve of target distance

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to create a curve between two points in PostGIS that meets some target distance. So my input is point_a, point_b, target_distance, and my desired output is a curve between those two points of approximately target_distance. I'd want to find curves both in the 'left' and 'right' direction.

I have hacked together the below using another StackOverflow post as a source. This produces a curve like I want (and I can negate the st_length to invert the curve), and I can modify the figure I divide ST_Length by to increase/decrease the size of the curve.

However, I can't immediately figure out the maths that will allow me to get from a target distance to this divisor. Any suggestions?

Of course, if there is a simpler way to achieve this I am all ears!

```
\pset pager off
\set point_a ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(0.0098956, 51.4831476),4326)
\set point_b ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(0.0000000, 51.52156),4326)
\set line_ab ST_MakeLine(:point_a, :point_b)

-- Direct distance: 4328.567m
SELECT ST_Length(:line_ab::geography);

-- Produces a slight curve of distance 4377.397m
SELECT ST_Length(
        ST_CurveToLine('CIRCULARSTRING(' || 
                       st_x(st_startpoint(:line_ab)) || ' ' || st_y(st_startpoint(:line_ab)) || ', ' || 
                       st_x(st_centroid(ST_OffsetCurve(:line_ab, st_length(:line_ab)/10, 'quad_segs=4 join=bevel'))) || ' ' || 
                       st_y(st_centroid(ST_OffsetCurve(:line_ab, st_length(:line_ab)/10, 'quad_segs=4 join=bevel'))) || ', ' || 
                       st_x(st_endpoint(:line_ab)) || ' ' ||  st_y(st_endpoint(:line_ab)) || ')')::geography
);

-- Produces a large curve of distance 9615.056m
SELECT ST_Length(
        ST_CurveToLine('CIRCULARSTRING(' || 
                       st_x(st_startpoint(:line_ab)) || ' ' || st_y(st_startpoint(:line_ab)) || ', ' || 
                       st_x(st_centroid(ST_OffsetCurve(:line_ab, st_length(:line_ab)/1, 'quad_segs=4 join=bevel'))) || ' ' || 
                       st_y(st_centroid(ST_OffsetCurve(:line_ab, st_length(:line_ab)/1, 'quad_segs=4 join=bevel'))) || ', ' || 
                       st_x(st_endpoint(:line_ab)) || ' ' ||  st_y(st_endpoint(:line_ab)) || ')')::geography
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect solution, but I found that I could use the formula to approximate the arc length of an ellipse to do what I want.

The arc length of the ellipse formula relies upon knowing the two radiuses, and it will give you the arc length (divided by 2 because we just want half the arc length). We just need to rearrange that formula to make one of the radiuses the subject and we're done.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901129/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-estimate-the-arc-length-of-an-ellipse for more details